# openCV: reading submat while sliding over bigger Mat

Tags: java, opencv

I want to read a **fixed-size-submat** from a **bigger Mat** while sliding it over the bigger one pixel by pixel (or maybe 5 pixel by 5 pixel or somtheing like that, i hope you get the idea).
 ***Is there a predefined function for that in openCV, if so which one is it?*** 
(Besides i am using Java with opencv 2.4.5..) I have an idea how to write it myself in java using `Mat.submat(a,b,c,d)`, but i thought that the underlying **c++ dll implementation** would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
cv::Mat I; // large mat
cv::Rect win; // sub mat
win.width = 5;
win.height = 5;
for(size_t i=0;i<I.rows-5;++i)
  for(size_t j=0;j<I.cols-5;++j)
  {
    win.x = i;
    win.y = j;
    I(win) //<- this is the submat
  }
```

`

Comment: I have coded a Java version of my own already. My question was different: I was asking wether there is a pre-implemented (thus faster, because it is in C++) function in Java openCV? Your answer shows, that you haven't understood this.